# How to dynamically create postgreSQL connection pools in node.js using the node-postgres package and export them for usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have an application where I need to create a new database for a new company that subscribes to use this application. So I'm maintaining a master database that stores this companies list and their respective database names. Now when the new company needs to use this newly subscribed application I need to create a new `Pool` for their database for usage. How to create it programmatically and export it in `node.js`?

I tried a way. I thought the pool as a simple object, so I tried to create it after it's database is created and stored it in the master database and tried to use that pool object whenever required (one pool is enough for me and I don't want to disconnect the pool as it should run 24/7, that's why I stored it). But I failed with the following error statement when I tried to connect to it

`TypeError: myPool.connect is not a function`

because once I store it as a jsonb in masterdb it no longer is a pool.

Suggestions on how to approach this will be helpful.

Comment: from [docs](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool) just create new Pool(config) and pass host, user, timeout etc. and you have new Pool object. you can create it any function and just return it from this function. if yourPool.connect is not a function probably yourPool is not a pool. :P

Comment: My question was how to create that pool programmatically and export it for other files. I should not create the pool every time I want to use it. I need to create it once when the new database is created and export it. I need to be able to access the previous pools too. Basically I need multiple pools stored somewhere and exported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// eg. poolBuilder
const { Pool } = require('pg')

const pools = new Map();
function getPool(companyName){
   if(!pools.has(companyName){
     pools.set(companyName,  new Pool({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'database-user',
      max: 20,
      idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
      connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000,
    }))
   }
   return pools.get(companyName);
}

module.exports.getPool = getPool;
```

```js
const {getPool} = require("poolBuilder");

const pool = getPool();
```

Comment: The `!pool` does the trick of not creating the pool more than once. Thanks. Now, I will make that pool variable as an object and do `if(pool.companyName === undefined)` in your code and `return pool.companyName`. Is that right?

Comment: yeap. if you need more pools you can store them in object or more correct as dictionary this means new Map(). but it can be object as well